# event click not working same class on multiple anchor tag in td elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

i am using dataTables plugin for showing data as a grid but thier is attribute formatter in which i am am appending anchor a in td as well as applying class on this but when i am binding event it's not firing instead it's refreshing page i don'nt know why can any one about this let me correct what's going wrong.

Its showing perfectly image in grid as well class showing but behaviour is wiered regarding click event fire its refreshing page when i am clicking.

**main.js:-**

```
$(".deleteRequest a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("click");
    var r=confirm("Are u sure you want to delete This Request info");
            if (r==true)
            {

            }           
});

 formatter: function (timeOutes) {
                    $.each(timeOutes, function (index, timeOut) {
                        timeOut.id = '<a attrId = " ' + timeOut.id + '" href="" class="deleteRequest"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>';
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the links default actions (postback most likely) --

```
e.preventDefault(); //add me to your click handler!
```